# Validating a form hiding controller from URL Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm facing a problem when trying to create a simple login system. This is how it works and shows what my problem is.

The login page contains a simple form, and opens a form to the controller 'Verify_login'. This Verify_login controller does some basic form validations, and then queries the database to check if the user entered correct credentials. When this form is submitted, it automatically directs the user to website.com/verify_login, while I would like it to remain website.com/login. I am not able to solve this problem using the routes file, because this causes the two pages to be both redirected to the same page. Does anyone have a solution to this? I'm using the Codeigniter framework.

**login.php**

```
<div class="content-block">
<h1>Login</h1>
<div class="content-inner-block">
    <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
    <?php echo form_open('Verify_login'); ?>
        <div class="login wrap">
            <input type="text" name="username" id="user" placeholder="Username">
            <input type="password" name="password" id="pass" placeholder="**********">
            <input type="submit" value="Log in">
        </div>
    <?php echo form_close("\n")?>
</div>
```

**Verify_login.php**

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class Verify_login extends CI_Controller{

        public function index(){

            $this->load->model('User_model');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
                $this->load->view('pages/login');
                 return false;
            }

            $result = $this->User_model->login($this->input->post('username'), $this->input->post('password'));
            if($result){
                echo 'loggedin';
            } else {
                echo 'wrong';
            }   

        }

    }
?>
```

Comment: Why not use `$.ajax` to submit the form? Or have the `login` controller call a private method to verify?

Comment: @Kisaragi So If I were to change the Verify_login public function to private, it would solve the problem?

Comment: No, that wouldn't solve your problem. Your form is posting to `verify_login`. Either change that (post to `login` and call a private method from login to verify) or use ajax to post to `verify_login`

Comment: @Kisaragi So you're saying I should post the form to itself, and call a private method from that view file? That's against the MVC principles I believe.

Comment: No. Do you have a `login.php` controller?

Comment: @Kisaragi No, the login page posts directly to the Verify_login? So I should make a login controller and move to verify_login from there?

Comment: If you don't want to redirect when post you must use ajax. WHAT is your current URL structure? `site_url/login`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122124/discussion-between-pat4561-and-kisaragi).

Comment: @Pat4561 can you briefly explain me what you need as answer

Comment: @Spartan I think I already solved it, I am using Ajax post now.